# Ajax Framework Using Dynamically Generated Links

Tags: ajax, navigation

I know, for links to be **ajaxified** they need to have a class: "use-ajax" and a proper url which has its own callback. For example:

```
<a href="ajax-reader/nojs/1/2015-03-05" class="use-ajax ajax-processed">Ajax Link</a>
```

If the link was statically created on the server, it works perfectly fine. But whenever I add a new link with the same properties, ajax seems not to work anymore. For instance, if I remove existing link and add a new one with new url parameters:

```
var ajaxRightUrl = 'ajax-reader/nojs/1/' + lastNextDate;
arrowLinkLeft.find('a').remove();
arrowLinkLeft.append('<a href="' + ajaxRightUrl + '"class="use-ajax"></a>');
```

It stops being an ajax link. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are probably missing the part to add behaviors to your new elements:

```
Drupal.attachBehaviors('.use-ajax');
```

Comment: Very good, that was it! I had the above code in a separate function outside attach: **function (context, settings)** So, I had to pass context parameter to my function and use it in your code: **Drupal.attachBehaviors('.use-ajax', context);** Thanks very much!